# Not able to save XML parsed response to database

Tags: android, listview, android-database

I am parsing a web service response with XMLPullParser and would like to store this in a local DB to be able to reduce the amount of network traffic as the API is not the most efficient for mobile.

I have created the database class and not sure how to place the response into the database then use that to get my information I need to populate my listview or hit the service again to get more data if needed because the database doesn't have it.

My DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

    //Contacts table columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "Employee_number";
    private static final String KEY_FIRST_NAME = "First_name";
    private static final String KEY_LAST_NAME = "Last_name";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE = "Phone_mobile";
    private static final String KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE = "Phone_office";
    private static final String KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE = "Payroll_title";
    private static final String KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS = "Has_direct_reports";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
    private static final String KEY_COST_CENTER = "Cost_center_id";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE + " TEXT"
                + KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE + " TEXT"
                + KEY_PAYROLL_TITLE + " TEXT"
                + KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS + " TEXT"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT"
                + KEY_COST_CENTER + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //drop old table if existence
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        //Create table again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Add new contact
    public void addContact(PeepWithPic peepWithPic) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, peepWithPic.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, peepWithPic.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, peepWithPic.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, peepWithPic.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, peepWithPic.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, peepWithPic.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, peepWithPic.getCost_center_id());

        //Inserting Row
        database.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        database.close();
    }

    //Get single contact
    public PeepWithPic getContact(int employeeNumber) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {
                KEY_ID, KEY_FIRST_NAME, KEY_LAST_NAME, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE,
                KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_COST_CENTER}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{ String.valueOf(employeeNumber)}, null, null, null, null);
        if( cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            PeepWithPic peepWithPic = new PeepWithPic(cursor.getString(0),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                    cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12),
                    cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16),
                    cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20),
                    cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24),
                    cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26));

            return peepWithPic;
    }

    //Get All Contacts
    public List<PeepWithPic> getAllContacts() {
        List<PeepWithPic> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        //Select all query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        //looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                PeepWithPic peepWithPic = new PeepWithPic();
                peepWithPic.setEmployee_number(cursor.getString(7));
                peepWithPic.setFirst_name(cursor.getString(9));
                peepWithPic.setLast_name(cursor.getString(11));
                peepWithPic.setPhone_office(cursor.getString(19));
                peepWithPic.setPhone_mobile(cursor.getString(18));
                peepWithPic.setHas_direct_reports(cursor.getString(10));
                peepWithPic.setEmail(cursor.getString(6));
                peepWithPic.setCost_center_id(cursor.getString(4));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        //return contat list
        return contactList;
    }

    //Get contact Count
    public int getContactCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        return cursor.getCount();
    }

    //Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(PeepWithPic peepWithPic){
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRST_NAME, peepWithPic.getFirst_name());
        values.put(KEY_LAST_NAME, peepWithPic.getLast_name());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_MOBILE, peepWithPic.getPhone_mobile());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER_OFFICE, peepWithPic.getPhone_office());
        values.put(KEY_HAS_DIRECT_REPORTS, peepWithPic.getHas_direct_reports());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, peepWithPic.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_COST_CENTER, peepWithPic.getCost_center_id());

        return database.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(peepWithPic.getEmployee_number())});
    }

    //Delete single contact
    public void deletedContact(PeepWithPic peepWithPic) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] {String.valueOf(peepWithPic.getEmployee_number())});
        database.close();
    }
}
```

MainActivity that has network call and listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView tappedListView, directReportListView;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    ArrayList<PeepWithPic> mPeepWithPics = new ArrayList<>();
    ListViewAdapter mAdapter;
    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* if toolbar is wanted by user uncomment
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/

        tappedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListView);
        directReportListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.clickedContactLV);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, mPeepWithPics);
        tappedListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        directReportListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        getXMLData();

        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(mPeepWithPics); // error is here
    }

    //Uncomment to add OptionsMenu(three dots on app bar) if needed
    /*@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/

    private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return builder.build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void getXMLData() {
        OkHttpClient client = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(getString(R.string.API_FULL_URL))
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                final String responseData = response.body().string();
                final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData.getBytes());
                XMLPullParserHandler parserHandler = new XMLPullParserHandler();
                final ArrayList<PeepWithPic> peepWithPics = (ArrayList<PeepWithPic>) parserHandler.parse(stream);
                mPeepWithPics.clear();
                mPeepWithPics.addAll(peepWithPics);


                //tell adapter on the UI thread its data changed
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        tappedListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        directReportListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

}
```

On the line databseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(mPeepWithPics); I am getting an error that says Error:(59, 47) error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to Contex. Not sure what that even means. I am just trying to save my reponse from OkHttp3 call to the database so I can use the database to show information or make another call to get more data when needed as this web service is very slow.

I added this to the constructor. I know get Error:(59, 72) error: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be converted to PeepWithPic. Little confused on how to pass this as I need to pass the Model to save to the localDB but I need it as an ArrayList to show it in the ListView adapter.

```
databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext(), mPeepWithPics); //this is in MainActivity

private final PeepWithPic peepWithPic;
public DatabaseHandler(Context context, PeepWithPic peepWithPic) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.peepWithPic = peepWithPic;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is kind of vague, or at least very broad.  What part are you stuck on?  Are you seeing errors?

Comment: I have updated my question at the bottom. Thank you for pointing out that it wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting an error that says Error:(59, 47) error: incompatible
>   types: ArrayList cannot be converted to Contex. Not sure what that
>   even means.

You should consider doing some basic Java training so that you can understand the messages your IDE is giving you.  This is telling you that the constructor is expecting a `Context` and you're trying to pass in an `ArrayList`.  You need to pass in a `Context`, probably the `MainActivity` instance (`this`).

Comment: I have passed getApplicationContext to the databaseHandler and I can run the app. What I am trying to do is add the response from the web service call to the database but not sure how to do that. Most guides I have read are hardcoding a list of information to their database. I have treid databaseHandler.addContact(mPeepWithPics) but I know that does not work as it wants the Model and I am trying to pass it an ArrayList

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where your problem is.  You know how to get a list of items into the database?  So is the issue with converting the server response into a list of objects?

Comment: Im having a problem with passing peepWithPics to the databaseHandler. Even when I take the parsed response in onResponse and try to pass it to databasehandler.addContact I am getting the error where I can not take an ArrayList and convert it to the Model class. I understand why, but not sure how to pass the parsed ArrayList in onResponse() to the database.

Comment: It sounds like you need a method in your database class that accepts a list of objects and inserts them all.

Comment: Let me reiterate that you could benefit from some beginner Java and Android tutorials.  I'm getting the impression you don't really understand the difference between different kinds of objects, which is fundamental to programming in Java, and this is leading to your confusion about why you can't pass an ArrayList instead of a Context, or how to pass a list of objects to a method that's expecting just one of them.

Comment: Will look into finding some on the internet, any suggestions on preferred ones? I do have access to Lynda.com

Comment: I don't know any to recommend specifically.

Answer (score 0):

DatabaseHandler constructor parameter is context but you inject ur model.

**change this:**

```
 public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

**to**

```
 public DatabaseHandler(Context context, Mymodel model) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.model = model;
    }
```

Comment: Updated the end of the code where I am getting confused with the error. I need to pass the model to save to LocalDB but need to have it as an ArrayList to populate the adapter for the listview.